# Is it possible to redefine a macro's parameter?

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex, def

I would like to redefine a macro parameter. This is what I have tried so far:

```latex
\def#1{$#1$}
```

But it throws this nasty error that I don't know how to fix.

```
! Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.66     \def#
              1{$#1$}
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

My actual goal is to do something of the following:

```latex
\def#1{\noexpand{{#1}}
```

But it throws the same error. I want to do this just to prevent `#1` from expanding later in the macro.

Comment: Perhaps you should start by explaining what your end goal is. What you are doing here does not make much sense.

Comment: Sorry, but it's difficult to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @daleif my bad. I thought I should provided a MRE, I'll edit now.

Comment: You need to provide a macro name. E.g., `\def\zzz#1{\noexpand{#1}}`.

Comment: Redefining a parameter in the way you show it is apparently not possible. But if you would make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and show the *actual goal* maybe it can be achieved within the command definition or the call of the command.

Comment: OTOH, if you are inside another macro where #1 is already defined, (as a macro name) then this would create a "quark", which would cause an infinite loop if expanded.

Comment: `\noexpand{` applies `\noexpand` to `{` which is not expandable.  It is really hard to guess what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Does @CATboardBETA perhaps mean they want to write a literal #1 later in the macro? If so this can be done by putting a backslash before the # (\#1).

Comment: about the same question already: what do you want to do with `#1` (or `$#1$`, for that matter)?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to guess your intent from your post, but I guess you mean something like this which locally redefines the command given as `#1` (`\TeX` here) to be safe in an `\edef`.

```
\def\LocallyMakeSafe#1{%
\edef\tmpA{#1}%
\immediate\write20{aaa: \meaning\tmpA}%
{%
\def#1{\noexpand#1}% local \protect
\edef\tmpB{#1}%
\immediate\write20{bbb: \meaning\tmpB}%
}%
}



\LocallyMakeSafe\TeX



\bye
```

Produces a log showing the effect before and after `\def#1`

```
aaa: macro:->T\kern -.1667em\lower .5ex\hbox {E}\kern -.125emX
bbb: macro:->\TeX
```

Comment: Clever, but it's really counterproductive to encourage such a radical redefinition of the essential TeX syntax.

Comment: @barbarabeeton huh?? latex does this sort of thing all the time \MakeRobust is more or less exactly this

Comment: The LaTeX team knows what they're doing.  Letting this loose on an audience that has demonstrated that they often *don't* know the basics is asking for more unintelligible questions.  Not everybody can create (or even unravel) `xii.tex`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton any command that defines anything does this: `\newcommand`, `\DeclareMathAccent`,  `\DeclareMathSymbol`, ... I do not see what is radical here, every command other than `\def` that defines anything will have `\def#1` in its definition.

Comment: Interesting to see barbara and David having a discussion.